# Creating a stored function on SQL of average scores, error code 1064

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, syntax

I keep throwing an error code when I try to create a stored funtion for netflix average IMD scores for 3 tables. The code works on it's own but not as a stored function. The answer returns as 7.9999 so I wanted to try to reduce the decimal output in the process to only two decimals, such as 7.9.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Average_Netflix_Score (
Score INT
) 
RETURNS DECIMAL (2, 2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE average_score DECIMAL (2, 2);

SELECT AVG(SCORE) INTO average_score
    FROM (
        SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_19
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_20
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_21
    ) AS CombinedScores;
    
    RETURN avg_score;
END;
```

Expected stored function to save with a value of 7.9 as outcome. But got syntax error code 1067.

Comment: This doesn't look like SQL Server syntax, it uses @ for variables among other issues

Comment: sorry it is SQL workbench

Comment: I think you mean MySQL? It's a good start when asking question to get the name of the database product correctly

Comment: "SQL Workbench" isn't an RDBMS. SAying that's the database you're using is like saying Visual Studio is the programming language you're using.

Comment: Also tell us the *actual* error, not just the error code.

Comment: Why do you have separate tables anyway? These should be all in one table with a year column.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `DECIMAL (2, 2)` means a total of 2 digits, of which 2 are decimals, i.e. values like `.25`.

But you probably want `DECIMAL (4, 2)`, to be able to give values like `12.75`.

Comment: thanks, will update this now, I was confused how to decimal were reflected, i thought it would be more 2 for each, so 00.00

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION Average_Netflix_Score (
  Score INT
  ) 
  RETURNS DECIMAL (2, 2)
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE average_score DECIMAL (2, 2);

    SELECT AVG(SCORE) INTO average_score
    FROM (
      SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_19
      UNION ALL
      SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_20
      UNION ALL
      SELECT SCORE FROM NETFLIX_21
    ) AS CombinedScores;

    RETURN avg_score;
   END;
```

here shouldn't you RETURN average_score
as you declared the average_score but you have returned only avg_score so I think you should change the return avg_score to average_score